# Как организовать резервное копирование файлов сервера?

Tags: linux, администрирование, резервное-копирование

Стоит задача резервного копирования файлов пользователей на *unux сервере. Не по расписанию, а по мере добавления файлов. Т.е. важен абсолютно каждый файл. Как делать репликацию баз данных я примерно разобрался, да и информации есть много.

Первое и пока единственное, что приходит на ум, это при закачке файла на сервер, сразу же отправить его на второй сервер, и только после отправить ответ об успешном выполнении. Есть ли какие то подходы/инструменты для решения данной задачи?

Дополнения:

> А какая стратегия по поводу удаления файлов с сервера?

Если пользователь удаляет файл, его нужно удалить везде. Хранить удаленные файлы нет необходимости.

Комментарии по поводу lsyncd... Сейчас копаю в сторону стандартный возможностей ubuntu, думаю покроет все требования.

P.S. Планируется хранение изображений. Сжатые, менее мегабайта. До 100-200ГБ. Ни о каких терабайтах и гигабайтных файлах речи не идет. Хочу избежать потери файлов при выходе из строя оборудования/программного сбоя на сервере.

Comment: с таким запросом я бы смотрел в сторону [распределённых ФС](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_distributed_file_systems)... а в качестве простого решения (если убрать требование «только после отправить ответ об успешном выполнении»), я бы подвесил в качестве сервиса скрипт из `inotyfy`'я и `rsync`'а навроде [этого](https://bartsimons.me/sync-folders-and-files-on-linux-with-rsync-and-inotify/). `rsync` можно заменить любым другим способом синхронизации по вкусу; некоторые из них поддерживают `inotify` из коробки...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а разве `lsyncd` не делает то же самое, но из коробки?

Comment: @donRumata, яхз — не пользовался... я уже вскользь упомянул, что есть и другие средства синхронизации, и некоторые поддерживают `inotyfy` из коробки... и как говорили древние: «да воздастся каждой мыши по собственному кактусу!»

Comment: А какая стратегия по поводу удаления файлов с сервера?

Comment: В первую очередь в голову приходит inotify, но если файлов/каталогов очень много (от десятков тысяч), то можно случайно в лимиты упереться

Comment: @andreymal можно уточнить какие лимиты? Linux только изучаю. Как будет время буду активно искать информацию по inotify.